# How to pass value in a function when it press button

Tags: angularjs

When i click on Edit Me! button,it calls function which name is mySwitch in Controller.Now i also want id AND name with it,means how can i get particular id and name in mySwitch function?

```
<tbody>
<tr dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">

        <td>{{user.id}}</td>                            
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="mySwitch()">Edit Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This function call when I press Edit Me! Button

```
$scope.mySwitch = function() {

      // Here I want id and name....
       //When i press Edit Me! button This function is called...
};
```

Comment: You can pass user also like this : `<button ng-click="mySwitch(user)">Edit Me!</button>`

Answer (score 3):

A function has to be from the html as `mySwitch()` and you can pass it any number of parameters, like: `mySwitch(param1, param2, param3, etc)`. So, to get the user id and name, you should change your button to:

```
<button ng-click="mySwitch(user.id, user.name)">Edit Me!</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.mySwitch = function(id, name) {
    console.log('ID: ', id)
    console.log('Name: ', name)
};
```

#### or

```
<button ng-click="mySwitch(user)">Edit Me!</button>

$scope.mySwitch = function(user) {
    console.log('ID: ', user.id)
    console.log('Name: ', user.name)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your ng-click function to accept parameters.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="mySwitch(user.id, user.name)">Edit Me!</button>
```

Angular-controller:

```
$scope.mySwitch = function(id, name) {
  // Here you have id and name....
  };
```